# How to open and render a file in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I am getting an error in Excel say:

```
excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid
```

Hi I have a excel file that is being generated each morning. I want the user to be able to download the Excel file.

```
def export_daily_report(request):
    output = pd.read_excel('crontab_files/daily.xlsx')
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')

    # tell the browser what the file is named
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="daiy_export.xlsx"'

    # put the spreadsheet data into the response
    response.write(output)

    # return the response
    return response
```

I want to open the excel and then render the file so that the user can download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output` is a pandas `DataFrame` as implied in this line:

```
output = pd.read_excel('crontab_files/daily.xlsx')
```

Next you try to write this dataframe to the response, and get an error at the client:

```
response.write(output)
```

Instead you should simply return a [`FileResponse` object [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects):

```py
from django.http import FileResponse

def export_daily_report(request):
    return FileResponse(open('crontab_files/daily.xlsx', 'rb'), as_attachment=True, filename="daiy_export.xlsx")
```